# Silent Install of SQL Server Express 2012 from Inno Setup

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation, inno-setup, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to install SQL Server Express 2012 silently from my application installer created using Inno Setup. When running the following command from the command line, SQL Server Express 2012 is installed as I want only showing progress of the install but not allowing the user to enter any input.

Command line command that works:

```
C:\Users\Jason\Desktop>SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MYINSTANCE /INSTANCEID=MYINSTANCE /QS /HIDECONSOLE /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="builtin\administrators" /SKIPRULES="RebootRequiredCheck"
```

In order to do this from my Inno Setup script I have the following code:

```pascal
Exec(installName,
  '/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MYINSTANCE /INSTANCEID=MYINSTANCE /QS /HIDECONSOLE /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="builtin\administrators" /SKIPRULES="RebootRequiredCheck"',
  '',
  SW_SHOW,
  ewWaitUntilTerminated,
  ResultCode);
```

where `installName = SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe`

When run from the Installer the SQL Server Express 2012 installer starts but after the first information dialog it then shows the SQL Server Installation Center window and the user has to select the type of installation before the installer continues. They also have to agree to the license agreement which was not required when running directly from the command line.

Any ideas on how to run the installer silently from Inno Setup?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between running at the command line and running from Inno, if you're using the same parameters.  One thing that can get you into trouble with SQL Server in particular though is where you are installing it *from* -- in particular, the `{tmp}` folder is sometimes a long enough pathname that the install will fail because SQL Server's own subfolders added onto this will break the maximum path length limit.  See how it goes if you run the install from the same location within Inno as you did outside of it.

Comment: I tried running from the same location but with the same result. The installer runs and works but still requires user input when run from Inno Setup.

Comment: I'm using the following command line and it's working fine for me: `/QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE /ENU /InstanceName="MyInstance" /UpdateEnabled=False /Action=Install /Features=SQL /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic`

Comment: From the command line I am able to start the SQL Server Express Installer silently, but it is still prompting the user when the same command is executed from Inno Setup. I added '/FEATURES=SQLENGINE' which was missing from my original example, but it still required user input.

Comment: One thing the license accept must be in capitals i.e. /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from "BUILTIN\Administrators" to "BUILTIN\Users" will be fine.

Comment: I marked this as the answer seeing that it did achieve the result of the installer running in silent mode. However, if I understand correctly this means that all users regardless whether or not they are Administrators will have Sysadmin rights to the SQL Server Express database instance. Is this the correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with passing command line params to `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe`
If you run extracted SQL setup.exe with your command linie all should be OK. But if you pass a command line through `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` it first extracts installer and then runs it with modified command line - one pair of quotation marks `""` is removed (or rather it passes only first string as params). That's why whole command line params for `setup.exe` should be placed in additional quotation marks `""`
Your command line should looks like this one (starts with `'` and `"` and finishes with `"` and`'`):

```
'"/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MYINSTANCE /INSTANCEID=MYINSTANCE /QS /HIDECONSOLE /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="builtin\administrators" /SKIPRULES="RebootRequiredCheck""'
```