# vb.net and sql database application installer

Tags: sql, vb.net

Bit newbie to this but, I am trying to develop an application with vb.net and sqlexpress. My application works perfect it connects to database and shows data on datagrids and all. Now, i wanted to install this application on another computer..... so i added .net freamework and sql express 2012 in prerequisites and have added set up project to main project as well. when i built setup and used on another computer, installing process works with no errors but it does not install sql express at all. thus application does not work. I have seen lots of pages related to one click install with prerequisites and applied solutions but it seems it just does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I'd advocate for dropping Visual Studio Setup projects and learning something like Inno Setup. Once you get the hang of Inno Setup, installing dependencies is so much easier and cleaner.

Comment: can i add ms sql express 2017 installation with inno? I tried creating example project with it but dont know where to add installation.

Comment: Check this out. It's for SQL Server Express 2012 but the concept should be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449975/silent-install-of-sql-server-express-2012-from-inno-setup

Comment: Thanks will try it today :-)